# java program to display whether strings are palindrome and also show if not which characters don't match

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

I have written a program which checks whether two strings are palindrome or not. If they are not then it tells which characters do not match. Code is as:

```
public void checkPalindrom() {
    boolean success = true; // success indicates whether palindrome or not
    boolean done = false; // it is used to stop the while loop
    int i = 0; // i wil be used as an index of the inputString

    while (!done) {
        // until the end of inputString or it encounters '#' character
        // take each character in inputString from left and add it to charStack and charQueue
        while (true) {
            if (i == inputString.length())
                break;
            else if (inputString.charAt(i) == '#') {
                break;
            }
            char ch = inputString.charAt(i);
            charStack.push(ch);
            charQueue.add(ch);
            ++i;
        }

        // prints out the substring extracted from the input string using queue's toString method
        System.out.print("The input " + charQueue.toString());

        // until the charQueue or charStack becomes empty
        // remove a character from each of charStack and charQueue, and check if they are same.
        // If they are different, then print out the approproate message (" is not a palindrome\n")
        // and also print which first set of two characters are different
        // ("The characters ' ' and ' ' do not match\n\n") -- note that you need to print
        // two such characters inbetween ' '
        // Also set success to false, so that the following "if" statement will be skipped
        char ch1, ch2;
        success = true;
        while (!charQueue.isEmpty()) {
            ch1 = charQueue.pop();
            ch2 = charStack.pop();
            if (ch1 != ch2) {
                System.out.print(" is not a palindrome \nThe characters '" + ch1 + "' and '" + ch2 + "' do not match\n\n");
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success == true)
            System.out.print(" is a palindrome\n\n");
        // i reaches the end of string, it is done processing the inputString
        if (i == inputString.length())
            done = true;
        else {
            i++;
            success = true; // set it back to true for the next substring to check
        }
    } // end of while loop
} // end of checkPalindrome( ) method
```

I am not getting the expected output and its failing for some of the cases. Can anyone please help me out how to fix this algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of such a concrete case? Where does it work, where does it not?...

Comment: What index do you return if both are of different length and thus not palindrome?

Comment: @thebenman the stack and the queue come from the same input string, so they are always the same size.

Comment: @OleV.V. I read two string in the question. Thus the confusion.

Comment: If your goal is to only determine if two given strings are palindrome or not and to find the character which is not, then why are you using `stacks` and `queues` when this entire thing can be done using `arrays`. Is there any specific reason why you are using these data structures?

Answer (score 0):

If your `inputString` contains more than one palindrome candidate separated by `#`, for example `"deified#racecar"`, you need to clear the queue and the stack before testing the second (and third) words. Otherwise letters from the first word will invalidate your result.

```
    while (!done) {
        charStack.clear();
        charQueue.clear();
        // until the end of inputString or it encounters '#' character
        // take each character in inputString from left and add it to
        // charStack and charQueue
        while (true) {
```